# Visual C# .net 2013 & Threads how-to

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm normally developping in java but I have now to develop a little wpf application using visual c# 2013 and ... it seems to be more complex than java.
So perhaps I will have lot of questions about it.

For the moment I'm working on threads.
And my first question is : what is the difference between that two ways for creating threads

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void Threads_Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(doSomething1);
        th1.Start();

        Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doSomething2));
        th2.Start();
    }
    private void doSomething1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting doSomething1");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing doSomething1");
    }
    private void doSomething2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting doSomething2");
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing doSomething2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are dealing with `Thread` objects in VS 2013 (I'm assuming you are targeting .NET 4.0+) instead of `Task` objects? Tasks can make things simpler.

Comment: Good question but ... don't know the response.  Quite new in .net world.  (and see my 2nd comment on the Stormenet answer)

Comment: See my answer with a starter on how to use Tasks instead

Comment: If you're unsure of the response, the answer is quite simply: "No, there is no reason" Take a look at the answer provided by @ledbutter. The answer Stormenet provided answers your question, but it's definitely worth looking into the other answer for more information.

C# is simple once you get used to it, I think Java expects more from the developer in comparison.

Comment: [Here is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx) the reasoning for using Task-based API, from the developers of Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storment's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21187084/1346943) is correct, but I thought I'd chime in with an alternative way of doing what you are doing that is considered best practice: using [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). I am assuming that since you are using VS 2013 that you are targeting .NET 4.5 so you also have the `async'/`await`keywords available to you. With your current little example app, you are going to run into trouble if you try to update your UI from`doSomething1()`or`doSomething2()` because only the UI thread can modify UI controls and those methods are running on different threads.

I'd suggest instead doing something like this:

```
//notice the async keywords in the method declarations
private async void Threads_Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   tasks.Add(doSomething1());
   tasks.Add(doSomething2());
   //this will wait until both doSomething1() and doSomething2() are done in a non-blocking fashion
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
private async Task doSomething1()
{
   //you can now update UI controls here
   Console.WriteLine("Starting doSomething1");
   await Task.Delay(3000);
   Console.WriteLine("Finishing doSomething1");
}
private async Task doSomething2()
{
   //you can now update UI controls here
   Console.WriteLine("Starting doSomething2");
   await Task.Delay(6000);
   Console.WriteLine("Finishing doSomething2");
}
```

This is obviously much different than what you have right now, but (other users, please correct me if you have a quibble with this statement), with "modern" .NET, you really shouldn't need to spin up your own threads in a WPF application like this. This again assumes you are targeting .NET 4.5, which, by default, VS 2013 will do (to be more pedantic, it would be 4.5.1 but that is immaterial in this context).

If you are interested in using `async`/`await` instead, I'd suggest reading up on it, perhaps by starting with the helpful [FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) on the Parallel Programming blog on MSDN and/or with Stephen Cleary's [intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Tanks.  Very usefull answer.  I just tried and working fine.  Just one remark,if I can ;-), I think the await in front of Task.WhenAll is not good.

Comment: Why is it "not good"? It simply makes it known to the compiler that execution should resume in `Threads_Button_Click_1` once all tasks have completed.

Comment: Because when I try like you write it I got this error (sorry it's in french) : L'opérateur 'await' peut seulement être utilisé dans une méthode async. Marquez cette méthode avec le modificateur 'async' et changez son type de retour en 'Task'.

Comment: I will not claim to understand French, but I believe that error message indicates that you did not mark `Threads_Button_Click_1` with the `async` keyword (look at my example code again)

Comment: Ok, back again to office.  In fact, in my doSomething2, I'm listening on a socket.  So I have : ... int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data,ref ep);  And now at this point everything is blocked (UI + doSomething1)

Answer (score 5):

They are both the same, what you see there happening is syntax sugar called [Delegate Inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163970.aspx#S10).

> Delegate inference allows you to make a direct assignment of a method
>   name to a delegate variable, without wrapping it first with a delegate
>   object.

In simple words, the compiler sees that the `doSomething1` method matches a `ThreadStart` Delegate so just creates one for you. It knows it should match the `ThreadStart` because that's in one of the constructor's parameters.

For more possibilities (with lambdas etc...) see [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2008/09/23/delegate-type-inference-in-c.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  In fact it is more complicated than java.  Lot of work in perspective.

Comment: Stupid question, but are 'visual c#' and 'c# .net' the same ?

Comment: Visual C# is Microsoft's implementation of the C# specification and includes libraries to make building Windows-specific programs easier, such as making interactive windows themselves. C# is the standard language with standard libraries.